# Calling button from RootPageViewController causes error

Tags: ios, swift

To change view on click on a UIBarButtonItem I'm trying to call a button inside of my `RootPageViewController`. On click the view shall change. Anyways, as soon as I start the app, following error occurs (Xcode doesn't detect any error as long the app is not started):

For `secondViewController.buttonPlus.action = #selector(addData(_:))`:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Additionally, when I try `print(secondViewController.buttonPlus)`, the result is `nil`.

In case you know a different approach to change view, please let me know.

**RootPageViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timelineView")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView")
        let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addView")

        return [vc1, vc2, vc3]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        if let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1] as? MainViewController {
            secondViewController.buttonPlus.action = #selector(addData(_:))
            self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    @objc func addData(_ sender: Any) {
        if let thirdViewController = viewControllerList.last {
            self.setViewControllers([thirdViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

**MainViewController:**

`````
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonPlus: UIBarButtonItem!

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        }

    ````
`````

Comment: Are you sure `buttonPlus` is connected to a `UIBarButtonItem` that is part of `MainViewController`?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, just connected it again to be safe - even Xcode suggests that there is a `buttonPlus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of two lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self
    if let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1] as? MainViewController {

        // call this first
        self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        // now you have access to buttonPlus
        secondViewController.buttonPlus.action = #selector(addData(_:))

    }

}
```